# What could be the causes for the changing behavior of EF in my environment regarding dbContexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

So it was time for my biennial cleanup of my developer environment, so I had the database backed up, drives formatted and software reinstalled.

No major changes in regards to development environment, except the change from sql express to localDB.

However, after I restored the database I soon noticed that entity framework refused to do anything but reads from it. When I tried to delete something I got this:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

So when googling this, I found out about the problem with handling objects in different instances of the dbContext. So by making sure that I used the same withing one call, it started to work again.

However, I'm not sure what triggered this changing behavior. Before the reset of my computer, I tried out both using a singleton instance of the dbContext which worked but was recommended against due to multi-threading issues. I then quick-hacked this to return a new instance each time, for each and every action on EF, which actually worked fine, even though I now don't understand how it could work due the current failure I experienced.

**So my question is, what could be the change in my environment that triggered this new behavior, making me unable, quite understandably, to use a new dbContext for each EF-action?**